# joining two components of string and identifying components

Tags: java

Can I please get help on how to join two components of the class term together, and how to identify and translate (using integer.parseInt) components in a string? the two components being "element" and "atoms".

I need to separate terms, from example from H20 to H and 20, identifying H as the element and 20 as the number of atoms. The "TODO" parts are where my code needs to be, the first "TODO" needs to be joining the two components, and the second "TODO" needs to identify components in string and translate them.

I am coding this in BlueJ and i am a beginner at coding, not too familiar with parsing and concatenating char and int. The whole chemical formula used for this computer science project is CH3CH2CH2CH2CH2CH3, these are the first questions.

I do not have an implementation as yet, because I do not know how to begin the code in the TODO sections.

```
public class Term 
{
private char element;
private int  atoms;
// creates a Term with the provided values
public Term(char element, int atoms)
{
this.element = element;         
this.atoms = atoms;
}
// creates a Term by parsing s      
// e.g. "H20" would give element = 'H', atoms = 20 

public Term(String s)
 {
 // TODO
}          
// turns the Term into a String      
// e.g. element = 'C', atoms = 4 would give "C4"
public String display()   
{        
// TODO          
return ""; 
}         
// returns the current value of element
  public char getElement() 
{
return element;
} 
// returns the current value of atoms
public int getAtoms()
{         return atoms;
}
}
```

Comment: ```String.valueOf(int)``` ?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, is the formula passed gonna be the smaller ones N times or the big one and should break it? Also show your implentation so far, the code you posted is cleary a snippet given by the teacher.

Comment: could you please expand on that?

Comment: @dambros I have editted to show what exactly needs to be coded in the "TODO" sections, and I have no implementation in place as that is what I need help doing here.

Comment: Is the pattern always N letters + N numbers? Or it can have a different pattern, where letters appear on the end, for examplr?

Comment: only a single letter can be used right now, and the number of atoms can be anything. since it is chemical formula, has to be letter first then number, eg H147 or C20

Comment: What kind of question it is.  It's blanked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class Term {
    private char element;

```
private int atoms;

// creates a Term with the provided values
public Term(char element, int atoms) {
    this.element = element;
    this.atoms = atoms;
}

// creates a Term by parsing s      
// e.g. "H20" would give element = 'H', atoms = 20 

public  Term(String s) {
    // TODO
    String e="";
    String at="";        
    char ch[]=s.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

        if(ch[i]>=(char)65 && ch[i]<=(char)90 || ch[i]>=(char)97 && ch[i]<=(char)122){
            e=e+ch[i];
        }
        else{
            at=at+ch[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("element = '"+e+"'\t atom = "+at);
}

// turns the Term into a String      
// e.g. element = 'C', atoms = 4 would give "C4"
public String display() {
    // TODO 
    String trm=""+getElement()+getAtoms();
    return trm;
}

// returns the current value of element
public char getElement() {
    return element;
}

// returns the current value of atoms
public int getAtoms() {
    return atoms;
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain your solution in your answer!

Comment: thank you for your input, but could you please explain the "for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

        if(ch[i]>=(char)65 && ch[i]<=(char)90 || ch[i]>=(char)97 && ch[i]<=    (char)122){
            e=e+ch[i];"

Comment: this is for determining whether it is alphabet or not.   ASCII codes from a-z [97 to 122] and for A-Z is [65 to 90]